# Tool Tip problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

css code

```
  /*********************/
/*      Tooltip      */
/*********************/

a.tooltip, a.tooltip:link, a.tooltip:visited, a.tooltip:active  {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: italic;
  }

a.tooltip:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  visibility:visible;
  }

a.tooltip span {
  display: none;  
  text-decoration: none; 
}

a.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 2000;
  color: #000000; 
  border:1px solid #000000; 
  background: #efefef;
  font-family : Verdana, Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
  font-size:    11px;
  text-align: left;
  }

a.tooltip span b {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2 2 2 2;
  font-family : Verdana, Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.analyzerGuiStatistics .queriesPerDayTable{
    border-spacing: 0px;   /* -> This property will not be interpreted correctly even up to IE 7; normally substitute for cellspacing="0"; */ 
    border-collapse: collapse;  /* this will work in ie and moz */ 
    width: 150px;
}
```

jsp code

```
<a class="tooltip"><%=results.getRecordCount()%>
<span>
  <b><bean:message bundle="AnalyzerTexts" key="queries.perDay"/></b>
   <table class="tooltip queriesPerDayTable">
    <%for (inta=0a<searchesAtDay.size();a++)   {                                                     if(a%2==0) {bgColor=brightBgColor;}
      else {bgColor=darkBgColor;}%>
     <tr class="<%=bgColor%>">
                                           <td><%=displayDateFormatMedium.format(logDays.get(a))%></td>
    <td class="config_el_align_right"><%=searchesAtDay.get(a)%></td>
   </tr>    
   <%} %>
  </table>
   </span>
   </a>
```

The above tooltip works well in firefox but not in IE?

Comment: How to accept? I have no idea.?

Comment: On your questions there will be a tick next to the answers that people have submitted, click the tick to accept an answer.

Comment: For starters, read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), then for each question you have asked navigate to that question and if a given answer solved your question then click on the "check mark" outline to accept the answer. All the questions you have asked are listed in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/663011/saurabh-kumar)

Comment: If you look at the link that Ocaso provided, all your questions will be answered.

Comment: Any of [THESE](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hover+ie) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support `:hover` on anchor tags without an `href` attribute.

You will need to add the attribute to your code to make this work in IE For example:

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#">
```

Answer (score 1):

to you question **how to accept answers**

[image]

1. L.H.S has a non selected answer, click the tick mark to make the answer **accepted answer**
2. The `1` indicates 1 vote up, `-1` indicates 1 vote down
3. To vote up press the `upward faced pyramid` and to vote down the other one, offcourse you need to have enough reputation points for that. So start accepting any answer for your questions and people will answer your questions happily :)

Hope this answers your question `How to accept? I have no idea.?`

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual question... however, it is an excellent explanation of how to accept answers. This should be on meta or the faq.

Comment: I will link to this answer whenever anyone asks "How to accept answers" :-)