# jquery closest tr not getting selected

Tags: jquery, closest, tablerow

using jquery 1.6.1

When the check box gets checked or unchecked, i want to change the background color of the row. My closest tr is not getting selected here. I have a working code that i am changing to plugin and this problem only happens in the plugin.

**Call:**

```
$(".tableHighlightSelector tr td input[type='checkbox']").checkBoxTableHighlighter();
```

**Plugin Code:**

```
//checkbox row highlighter
jQuery.fn.checkBoxTableHighlighter = function(options){
var defaults = {  
    highlightClass: "rowhighlight"
};  
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

var highlight = {
    RemoveHighlightForAllNotChecked: function ($item) {
        $item.filter(':not(:checked)').closest("tr").removeClass(defaults.highlightClass);
    },
    CheckBoxRowSelect: function (e, $clicked) {
        if ($clicked.attr("checked") == true) {
            $clicked.closest("tr").addClass(defaults.highlightClass);
            highlight.RemoveHighlightForAllNotChecked($('input[name=' + $clicked.attr("name") + ']')); //when we make checkbox behave like a radio button
        }
        else
            $clicked.closest("tr").removeClass(defaults.highlightClass);
    }
}
return this.each(function() {  
    var $obj = $(this);
    var jsObj = this;   
    //onload
    highlight.CheckBoxRowSelect('', $obj);     
    //click
    $obj.click(function(){
        highlight.CheckBoxRowSelect(e, $(this));
    }); 
    //keyup
    $obj.keyup(function(){
        highlight.CheckBoxRowSelect(e, $(this));
    });         
});
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="300px" class="tableHighlightSelector">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Group 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="a" checked="checked" /></td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="b" /></td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="c" /></td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="d" /></td>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Please accept some answers if they provided you with a solution. If you do not know how to accept an answer, please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960930/tool-tip-problem-in-internet-explorer/5962292#5962292)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have defined the `.rowhighlight` CSS class? I pasted this into jsFiddle and the highlighter worked straight away for `<input checked="checked">`!

There were some missing event variables on the click handlers which the Chrome console was reporting immediately.

```
$obj.click(function(e /* added e here */) {
    highlight.CheckBoxRowSelect(e, $(this));
});
```

I assume this was a copy&paste error otherwise you can't have been ever getting into the main `CheckBoxRowSelect` function.

The main problem overall is the *checking if an input is checked* logic which is incorrect. There are a [few ways to check if an input is checked in jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html) and your test was not working. Replacing with `if ($clicked.is(':checked')) {` as I have done in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKfW4/) fixes the logic and the row is highlighted.